# Subir imágenes con Invertervention Image

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy tratando de subir imágenes a una base de datos con Intervation Image en un formulario y cuando le doy al botón , la página se reinicia pero no sube la imagen.

No me dice ningún error y no sé como solucionarlo, tampoco se como añadirle el crear un thumbnail.

este es mi formulario

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Upload</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
        <meta name="csrf_token" content="{ csrf_token() }" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" ></div>

            <img src="{{asset('image/default.png')}}" width="200" height="200" alt="default">

            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {!! csrf_field()!!}

            <input type="file" name="image">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
                Save 
            </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y este es mi controllador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\image;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Images;

class imageController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
    $image = image::whereId('1')->first();
    return view('image', compact('image'));
   }

   public function post(Request $request)
   {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $fileName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        Image::make($image)->resize(200,200)->save('image/'.$fileName);
        $save = new image;
        $save->image = $fileName;
        $save->save();
        return redirect()->back();
   }
}
```

Y mis rutas

```
Route::get('/images', 'imageController@index');

Route::post('/postImage', 'imageController@post');
```

Comment: Estás utilizando `Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic` como `Images` y luego utilizas `Image::make`, no es `Images::make`?

Comment: Falta el action del formulario, agrégalo y si el problema persiste; entonces está relacionado con la forma en que procesas la imagen. Checa eso y vemos en que podemos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Primero verifica que en el formulario estes enviando la ruta postImage, no veo que especifiques la ruta, esta vacia...

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('postImage/') }}">
```

Revisa  bien como haces el llamado al post

Cuando hagas el llamado de la ruta quitale el / previo en el nombre asi:

```
Route::post('postImage/', 'imageController@post');
```

Cualquier cosa avisa.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice @KakosPro creo q el problema es que al hacer el make hacer Image:make() y no **Images:make()**. Yo en el path la hacer save tb suelo usar public_path() que es donde normalmente se guardan las imagenes( pero eso a tu gusto )

```
public function post(Request $request)
   {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $fileName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        Images::make($image)->resize(200,200)->save(public_path('image/'.$fileName));
        $save = new image;
        $save->image = $fileName;
        $save->save();
        return redirect()->back();
   }
```